# How to stop Azure App Service 'health check' feature to be reset after every deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Our web application is hosted with Azure App Service and the 'Health check' feature is enabled for this app.

[image]

I have noticed that every time I run a release pipeline (for deployment), this feature gets reset to Disabled settings.

[image]

How can I prevent this 'resetting' of health check setting? If it is impossible then is there a way to activate it during a pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it by using an Azure CLI task in the release pipeline. The task contains the following script:

```
az webapp config set -g $(resourceGroup) -n $(WebAppName) --generic-configurations "{\"healthCheckPath\": \"/health\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

***You need to add the Configuration setting in Release pipeline to enable Health Check like below:-***

[image]

[image]

```
healthCheckPath /api/health/
```

***After running the pipeline > Health check got enabled after adding the setting above in Release pipeline:-***

[image]

*In the pipeline Logs the Setting was applied successfully like below:-*

[image]